# How to set hard tabs in vim on Windows?

Tags: windows, vim, python

I have just installed Vim 8.1 on Windows 10. I use Vim for editing Python programs and would like autoindenting done with hard tabs set at four spaces. I am sure the relevant commands are:

set autoindent
set noexpandtab
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4

and I put these lines at the end of Program Files (x86)/Vim/vim81/_vimrc.

When I open a .py file with vim, there is autoindentation with hard tabs but tabs are set at 8 spaces (confirmed with :se ts). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a place for your user's local vimrc?  That is what I would suggest.

Comment: Afaik, the answer is "yes" and the correct place is the one I mentioned in my post. I am certain this is the correct place because if I put "set nu" in the file then Vim shows me files with line numbers and if I take the line out, it doesn't.

Comment: Sure, but that is the system wide vim config - not the user level config.

Comment: If I put some commands in a user level config file and they didn't work then one explanation would be that I am running Vim as a different user so Vim is not picking up the config. But you're saying I am putting the commands in a system wide config so they should work irrespective of which user I am - no?

Comment: I think they should. I develope on Linux, so I'm not %100 percent sure of locations on windows, but that sure looks like a path to systemwide settings.

Comment: You said some of the setting are working?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but I have solved my problem now by uninstalling Vim 8.1 and re-installing 7.3.

Comment: Glad you got it working.